# Select nth elements, except if element is at specific position and last-child with CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to select all elements with one selector, starting from the 4th. But I dont want to select that 4th, if it is the last element.

```css
.container div {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
}

.container div:nth-child(n+4):not(:nth-child(4):last-child) {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/e9fgdeu1/

Comment: Once browsers support level 4 :not(), what you have will work. In fact, your snippet will display the correct result in Safari 9+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think only one selector is not enough to get this. However it can be done with following selector:

```
.container div:nth-child(n + 5),
.container div:nth-child(4):not(:last-child) {
  background: red;
}
```

```css
.container div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}

.container div:nth-child(n + 5),
.container div:nth-child(4):not(:last-child) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.container div {
display: inline-block;
margin: 5px;
}

.container div:nth-child(n+4) {
background: red;
}

.container div:nth-child(4):last-child {
background: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thx, but is this also possible all in one selector? I dont want to reset the rules in a second selector.

Comment: I don't think its possible in one line. You can use :not to remove last-child but you need atleast two step for it.

Comment: :nth-last-child(1) is equivalent to :last-child and perfectly valid. It's not a typo.